# EPPlus set Connect data points with line

Tags: c#, epplus

I have already draw an excel chart with EPPlus in C# and I need to set Connect data points with line, in order to avoid empty cells affecting my chart.

[image: A correct sample of line chart that ignore Cleared cells and connect data points with line]

As you can see in above image, there are two cells with no value (Green ones) and I checked the "Connect data points with line" in excel data options.

But working with EPPlus, I cant find the proper property to set that.

Comment: you need to give an example code

Comment: I just uploaded related image example in excel.

Comment: maybe you can just find all the null values and filled them with 0? Because when displayed on the chart, they will be 0 anyway?

Comment: Filling with 0 cause the line chart, drop to X axis and made my chart hard to read. I want to connect two data points before and after the 0 or null cells to make my chart more readable like the attached image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, your reported problem of  EPPLus has not been resolved yet! So, as an alternative solution, switch cells whose data is null to #N/A.
In this case, Excel will correct the chart automatically.